# Sencha Store showing empty line on grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is probably an easy one to do with formatting, when I add a row to the grid it comes up blank

code to add the row:

```
var innerArray = Array(
        {'ID':'aaa','Text':'aaa'}
        );
searchCriteria.add(innerArray);
```

Code that makes the table

```
var searchCriteria = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
// store configs
autoDestroy: true,
storeId: 'myStore',
// reader configs
idIndex: 0,
fields: [
   'ID',
   'Text'
]
});
```

Panel

```
var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Search Criteria',
    layout: 'fit',
    height: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox', // Arrange child items vertically
        align: 'stretch', // Each takes up full width
        padding: 5
    },
    items: [{ // Results grid specified as a config object with an xtype of 'grid'
        xtype: 'grid',
        columns: [
            {
                header: 'ID'
            },
            {
                header: 'Text'  
            }
        ], // One header just for show. There's no data,
        store: searchCriteria,
        flex: 1 // Use 1/3 of Container's height (hint to Box layout)
    }]
});
```

Rows get added, but blank what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your grid columns, add a `dataIndex` property:

```
columns: [{
    header: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'ID'
},{
    header: 'Text',
    dataIndex: 'Text'
}
```

The `dataIndex` property is what tells the grid where to pull the information from in the stores model